# WPF application with several windows including a non active: focus issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, input, focus

I have a .Net 4 application with two windows in WPF 4:

- One uses the WS_EX_NOACTIVATE style to prevent gaining focus.
- The other is a basic Window.

The "no-activate" window behavior is appropriate as soon as I do not select the basic window (it doesn't gains the focus). But when the basic window is selected, the "no-activate" window can be focused... and gains it when the user clicked on it.

It is as if WPF considered two windows of the same application had the right to give focus even if they are not supposed to.
This behavior does not happen if both windows are WS_EX_NOACTIVATE.

Have you ever been faced with this problem?
I have read this: [WPF in Visual Studio 2010 – Part 3 : Focus and Activation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/09/wpf-in-visual-studio-2010-part-3-focus-and-activation.aspx), but does not solve it.

**Edit:** I have been able to get around by using a Popup as a base class for my no-active Window. However, I don't want to have a Popup. Why !? The popup never receives the focus: does someone know why / how ? How can I reproduce this behavior to a Window ? 
I try to step into Popup / Window code, but it is not very clear !

Thanks !

Comment: you dont want a window to become active ?? then why create the window, if its just to do some code, you can also add code files, or classes.. also there are .hide and .show and .activate as form actions.

Comment: The Window is needed. It is an OSK that need to never gain the focus. This project is opensource: [Civikey Website](http://www.civikey.fr/) [Civikey on GitHub](https://github.com/Invenietis/ck-certified).

Answer (score 0):

Try also giving it the WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW. 
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/273724/a-form-that-doesnt-steal-focus#

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It changes nothing... the Window still obtain the focus.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I partially solved the problem.

The Window already got the focus if it is directly selected, but it is not focused when a component of the window is selected.

Just add :

```
Focusable = false;
```

to any WPF controls contained in the Window and they will never been focused even if the previous focus is a Window of the same Application.